# How to change the response in MongoDB using translatable fields

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for the way how to resolve this and I can't find it. I appreciate your help.

I have a collection with products like:

```
[
    {
        "name": [
            { "es": "Producto 1" },
            { "en": "Product 1" }
        ]
        "reference": "PR1",
        "price": "20",
        "description": [
            { "es": "Descripción 1" },
            { "en": "Description 1" }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I would like to do:

db.products.aggregate(); // Find by language es for example:

And get:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Producto 1",
        "reference": "PR1",
        "price": "20",
        "description": "Descripción 1"
    }
]
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: This is not possible with find. You'd have to use aggregation or an alternative. How does your complete json look like?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick answer. Can you provide an example using agregation to have this response? Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a schema change though to this:

```
 [
        {
            "name" : [
                {
                    "language" : "es", 
                    "description" : "Producto 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "language" : "en", 
                    "description" : "Product 1"
                }
            ], 
            "reference" : "PR1", 
            "price" : "20", 
            "description" : [
                {
                    "language" : "es", 
                    "description" : "Descripción 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "language" : "en", 
                    "description" : "Description 1"
                }
            ]
        }
 ]
```

cause then you could actually group by the language in your case. 
If this is possible then you could do the following:

```
db.products.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$someName"},
{$unwind: "$someName.name"},
{$unwind: "$someName.description"},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {namelang: "$someName.name.language", namedesc: "$someName.description.language"},
        name: {$first: "$someName.name.description"},
        reference: {$first: "$someName.reference"},
        price: {$first: "$someName.price"},
        description: {$first: "$someName.description.description"}
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        "_id.namelang": "en",
        "_id.namedesc": "en"
    }
}
])
```

FYI since you didn't provided your complete json I created one random. Here is the complete schema:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ea07a600f5db2660dbf162"), 
    "someName" : [
        {
            "name" : [
                {
                    "language" : "es", 
                    "description" : "Producto 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "language" : "en", 
                    "description" : "Product 1"
                }
            ], 
            "reference" : "PR1", 
            "price" : "20", 
            "description" : [
                {
                    "language" : "es", 
                    "description" : "Descripción 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "language" : "en", 
                    "description" : "Description 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```